# How to use an horizontal scrollView while using createMaterialTopTabNavigator with swiping enabled, REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation, react-native-scrollview

i'm using **createMaterialTopTabNavigator** with a **swipeEnabled set to True** to navigate between screens, I have a Screen which contains an horizontal **scrollView**, the problems is that the scrollView isn't working, since whenever i try to scroll it horizontally the screen just changes to the next one.

I'd like to be able to disable the **swipeEnabled** when i swipe in the **scrollView**.

PS: i tried doing it dynamically by passing a variable to the Screen and a method that sets it to false using onTouchStart, but it's slower than the swiping event of the screen so it end up swiping to the next screen before onTouchStart event start.